# Laravel setup projects on personal web server

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I have at home a personal web server running apache where I have a /var/www/{project_folder} to serve my websites, where I access them by the other machines by the IP/{project_folder}, nothing new for now. :)

I have some new projects done with laravel, but I only run them at my local machine to use the cli command to serve where it always runs at localhost:{door}

I would like to put that projects at my web server but I'm facing some difficulties because I only have some basic knowledge about apache and I'm having trouble to figure out the configuration.

I believe someone have already done that :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan, but I have already checked that article and this is true but you have to change your hosts file.
Is there a way to do it the same way IP/{project_folder} without modifying the hosts file on the users end, for example, if someone comes over and I want to show him the project on his pc/tablet without access to hosts file?

Comment: You mentioned in your question you're having difficulties figuring out the configuration. Please elaborate on that, what have you tried doing so far and what's not working?

Comment: What's your question, son?

Comment: I believe it was specific. I didn't mentioned what I have already tried but I believe that asking how to put a laravel project on a dedicated personal web server and accessing it on the network via IP/{project_folder}, {project_folder} matching the name of the folder of the project that's on my web server root directory, I don't know what's unclear here. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you already have PHP working with Apache, so your httpd.conf file is fully configured so that if you have a file ending with .php will be handled properly.

All you have to do now is place your project in the htdocs folder where you have all normal project in. That's it.

You could install composer and install Laravel with it. For example via

```
"composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist".
```

[See here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation)

Now the tricky part:
If you want to access the site via http://localhost/your-project and not via http://localhost/your-project/public, then do this (depending on you OS):

- Activate Mod_Alias
- Goto '<IfModule alias_module>'

Then add this line inside:

```
 Alias /your-project/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/your-project/public/"
```

In this case you don't need virtual hosts.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have further questions regarding this.